# UWP animation is not proper when duration is set below 1 sec

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, uwp

I am animating a rectangle and a pair of lines[image: candle shape]

in uwp, such that the rectangle animates from its center and the lines animate from the top of the rectangle to its position. When I set duration less than 1 sec animation is not proper .
[image: line messed up with the rectangle]
But with the same duration(such as 0.8, 0.7) it is working fine in wpf. This occurs on initial loading, when on dynamically animating it works.

```
     Storyboard sb;
        Rectangle rect;
        Line highLine;
        Line lowLine;
        double width, height, x_center, y_center;

        private void DrawElement()
        { 
            rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            rect.Height = 60;
            rect.Width = 40;
            rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            rect.StrokeThickness = 2;
            rect.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
            grid.Children.Add(rect);

             width = grid.ActualWidth;
             height = grid.ActualHeight;
             x_center = width / 2;
             y_center = height / 2;        

            highLine = new Line();
            highLine.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
            highLine.StrokeThickness = 2;

            highLine.X1 = highLine.X2 = x_center;
            highLine.Y1 = y_center - rect.Height/2 - 30;
            highLine.Y2 = y_center - rect.Height/2;

            highLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            grid.Children.Add(highLine);  

            lowLine = new Line();
            lowLine.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
            lowLine.StrokeThickness = 2;

            lowLine.X1 = lowLine.X2 = x_center;
            lowLine.Y1 = y_center + rect.Height / 2 + 30;
            lowLine.Y2 = y_center + rect.Height / 2;

            lowLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            grid.Children.Add(lowLine);

            AnimationLogics();
        }
         private void AnimationLogics()
        {
            string rectPath = "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)";
            string y1_path = "Y1";
            string y2_Path = "Y2";

            sb = new Storyboard();

            //rect animation

            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = 0;
            da.To = 1;
            da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

#if !WPF
            da.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, rectPath);
#else
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(rectPath));
#endif
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, rect);
            sb.Children.Add(da);

            // high line animation

            DoubleAnimation da1 = new DoubleAnimation();
            da1.From = y_center;
            da1.To = highLine.Y1;
            da1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

#if !WPF
            da1.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, y1_path);
#else
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath(y1_path));
#endif
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, highLine);
            sb.Children.Add(da1);

            DoubleAnimation da2 = new DoubleAnimation();
            da2.From = y_center;
            da2.To = highLine.Y2;
            da2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

#if !WPF
            da2.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da2, y2_Path);
#else
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da2, new PropertyPath(y2_Path));
#endif
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da2, highLine);
            sb.Children.Add(da2);

            //low line animation

            DoubleAnimation da3 = new DoubleAnimation();
            da3.From = y_center;
            da3.To = lowLine.Y1;
            da3.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

#if !WPF
            da3.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da3, y1_path);
#else
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da3, new PropertyPath(y1_path));
#endif
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da3, lowLine);
            sb.Children.Add(da3);

            DoubleAnimation da4 = new DoubleAnimation();
            da4.From = y_center;
            da4.To = lowLine.Y2;
            da4.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

#if !WPF
            da4.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da4, y2_Path);
#else
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da4, new PropertyPath(y2_Path));
#endif
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da4, lowLine);
            sb.Children.Add(da4);

            sb.Begin();           
        }
        private void grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            grid.Children.Clear();
            DrawElement();
        }
```

Comment: You have not set a fixed postion for your line and rectangle, they will move by current window's size. I've tested your code in UWP and WPF, I cannot see the differences between the UWP and WPF. You could see the screen record:[https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KjSsz3wsYwqZkyltZ](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KjSsz3wsYwqZkyltZ)

Comment: I can notice the issue, I used your code in a simple UWP app with a rootgrid the lines and the rectangle don't seem to be aligned.

Comment: @Aditya I have updated this post. I have set fixed position but still facing the same. On initial loading this issue occurs, when I dynamically animate it was better than initial loading.